# Conservative vector field given in polar coordinates

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, curl

Given a vector field $F$ in polar coordinates, for the example the field $$\vec F(r,\theta)= -r \hat r + (r^2\sin \theta ) \hat \theta $$

I am asked to check if the field is conservative.
is it right to say that the curl of the field is not $0$, because $\frac d {dr} (r^2 \sin \theta ) - \frac d {d\theta} (-r) = 2r\sin \theta \neq 0$, and therefore the field is not conservative? Or do I have to change first the coordinates to cartesian coordinates and then do the same/other process? ( I had this question in an exam and the lecturer changed to cartesian coordinates before he made this process in his exam solution he published... )

Comment: The choice of the coordinate system is irrelevant. However, you need to use the curl operator in spherical coordinates as well.

Comment: @infinitezero so my answer correct? or not

Answer (score 1):

No, your approach is not correct. In polar coordinates the curl of $F$ is (see this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)):
$$\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial (r F_{\theta})}{\partial r}-\frac{\partial F_{r}}{\partial \theta}\right)=\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial (r^3\sin\theta)}{\partial r}-\frac{\partial (-r)}{\partial \theta}\right)=3r\sin\theta.$$
Hence the field is not conservative in any open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The same result can be found using cartesian coordinates:
$$F=-r \hat r + (r^2\sin \theta ) \hat \theta=(-x-y^2)\hat i+(-y-xy)\hat j$$
and therefore the curl of $F$ is
$$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (-y+xy)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (-x-y^2)}{\partial y}=
y+2y=3y$$
which coincides with the previous computation.

Comment: Understood, Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: sorry, but I actually do have a question about your answer: why did you compute $\frac {d(rF_\theta)} {dr}$ and not $\frac {dF_\theta} {dr} $ ? is this how you compute the curl of a field in polar coordinates? because I know that curl of a 2d vector such as $v(x,y)=(p(x,y), q(x,y))$ is just $q_x (x,y) - p_y (x,y)$...

Comment: Yes, that's the way we compute the curl of a field in polar coordinates. See at the linked webpage the curl in cylindrical coordinates (with $z=0$).

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen the link. thank you so much!